# Replace first instance NULL or ' ' with another value - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to replace the first instance of a NULl or '  ' value in a column with another value. But only the first instance and nothing else.

So far I've put this together:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column = CONCAT(REPLACE(LEFT(column , INSTR(column , '')), '', 'new_value'), SUBSTRING(column , INSTR(column , '') +1))
```

I could replace all the values but I don't want that:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column = REPLACE (column , 'old_value', 'new_value')
```

Comment: Do you want to update only one row?

Comment: Yes, only 1 row, determined by the column name. Basically the first instance of a NULL or ' ' value in a row determined by the column name. After that I want it to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Just try using `limit 1`

```
  UPDATE table_name SET column='new_value' WHERE column='' limit 1
```

Comment: It worked, I don't even know what to say...I gotta stop over-thinking these things.

Comment: What you should do is spend more time researching before asking a question. You've shown up in the close-queue with 2 different questions, both 8 hours ago. This means that you have at max spent 1 hour before moving from one question to another. One hour of research is peanuts, I suggest you spend more time on that and less on using SO the way you should use google. You have posed 8 questions in 2 days, 4 of which are already on hold. That's a bad track record.